# how to change style error message for required field

Tags: css

How do I change the message style? Or can I delete messages?
To be able to put this message background color or font changes?

[image: img]

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are using the [jQuery validate() plugin](http://jqueryvalidation.org/).

To change the message itself, you can do this through an attribute or through a function in your jQuery.

Attribute:

```
<form>
     <input name="firstname" required data-msg="Enter your custom message here">
</form>
```

jQuery:

```
$("form").validate({
        rules: {
            firstname: "required"
        },
        messages: {
            firstname: "Enter your custom message here"
        }
});
```

I highly recommend taking notes from their "Remember the Milk" example form, which customizes everything about the error messages.

http://jqueryvalidation.org/files/demo/milk/